# Most likely dice sequence given weights and switching probabilities

Tags: probability, dice

An occasionally dishonest casino uses two kinds of dice: a fair die that has $\frac16$ probability of rolling any number, and a loaded die that has $\frac12$ probability to roll a $6$ and a $\frac1{10}$ probability to roll each of the remaining numbers. The probability that the casino switches from the fair to loaded die is $0.1$ and the probability of switching back from loaded to fair is $0.05$. What is the most likely sequence of dice used if you observe the following numbers: $$4,6,6,6.$$ Assume the casino always starts with the fair die. Show your work.

Comment: Indeed, show your work. We're not just going to give you the answer.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good. As this question appears to be homework, please consider reading [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/8348) for information about asking _effective_ homework-related questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

There are $8$ different possibilities for the sequence of dice types ($\text{F}$ is fair, $\text{L}$ is loaded):

$$\text{FFFF}, \text{FFFL}, \text{FFLF}, \text{FFLL}, \text{FLFF}, \text{FLFL}, \text{FLLF}, \text{FLLL}$$

Let $A_i$, with $1 \leq i \leq 8$ denote the event that the sequence of dice is the $i^{th}$ of the $8$ configurations above. Find the probability $P(A_i)$ for each $i$.

Let $B$ be the event that the numbers shown are $4$, $6$, $6$, and $6$. Find $P(B)$. You have to be a bit careful at this step. $P(B)$ isn't just $(1/6)^4$ since switching the dice is possible.

Now you can use [Bayes' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem) to find $$P(A_i \mid B) = \frac{P(B \mid A_i) \cdot P(A_i)}{P(B)}$$

for each $1 \leq i \leq 8$.

---

Intuitively, I'd guess it's one of $\text{FFFF}$ or $\text{FLLL}$. You might be able to just apply Bayes' Theorem to those two cases; whichever gives the higher $P(A_i \mid B)$ is your answer.

It shouldn't be any of the others because switching multiple times is unlikely, and switching later in the sequence makes the second and/or third $6$ less likely.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So the most probable dice sequence is $\{Fair, Fair, Fair, Fair\}$. (T = Fair, F = Loaded)